# How to implement low-dimensional embedding layer in pytorch

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, layer, embedding

I recently read a [paper](http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~jmcauley/pdfs/aaai16.pdf) about embedding.

In Eq. (3), the `f` is a `4096X1` vector. the author try to compress the vector in to `theta` (a `20X1` vector) by using an embedding matrix `E`.

The equation is simple  `theta = E*f`

I was wondering if it can using `pytorch` to achieve this goal, then in the training, the `E` can be learned automatically.

How to finish the rest? thanks so much.

The demo code is follow:

```
import torch
from torch import nn

f = torch.randn(4096,1)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming your input vectors are one-hot that is where "embedding layers" are used, you can directly use [embedding layer](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html?highlight=embedding#torch.nn.Embedding) from torch which does above as well as some more things. `nn.Embeddings` take non-zero index of one-hot vector as input as a long tensor. For ex: if feature vector is

```
f = [[0,0,1], [1,0,0]]
```

then input to `nn.Embeddings` will be

input = [2, 0]

However, what OP has asked in question is getting embeddings by matrix multiplication and below I will address that. You can define a module to do that as below. Since, param is an instance of `nn.Parameter` it will be registered as a parameter and will be optimized when you call Adam or any other optimizer.

```
class Embedding(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_dim, embedding_dim):
        super().__init__()
        self.param = torch.nn.Parameter(torch.randn(input_dim, embedding_dim))

    def forward(self, x):
        return torch.mm(x, self.param)
```

If you notice carefully this is the same as a linear layer with no bias and slightly different initialization. Therefore, you can achieve the same by using a linear layer as below.

```
self.embedding = nn.Linear(4096, 20, bias=False)
# change initial weights to normal[0,1] or whatever is required
embedding.weight.data = torch.randn_like(embedding.weight)
```

Comment: Thanks, Does your code work for any feature vectors? it seems that the `f` is a `4096X1` vector and it can contain any number for the vector elements.

Comment: This code can work for any real-valued feature vector, since it is just a matrix multiplication. Though `nn.Embedding` expects one-hot features and expects you pass non-zeros indices as long tensor if I remember correctly. I am not sure if you are confused about that, if that is the case, I can elaborate more in my answer

Comment: Will the self.param update automatically if use Adam gradient? thanks

Comment: Hi @jason, I have updated my answer to reflect most of your queries